# Symfony Dependency Injection for Input and Output classes

Tags: symfony

For a project that I'm working on, using Symfony which I'm quite new to, I am trying to create an object of a class that uses Dependency Injection but also needs some custom parameters.

Now let's say I have a Command:

```
<?php

class ServerCommand extends Command {
    public function __construct(Server $server) {
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And a Server class:

```
<?php
class Server {
    public function __construct(MessageManager $messageManager, InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, the `Server` class is injected into the `Command` class and the `MessageManager` class is injected into the `Server` class.

The problem that I'm having is getting the `$input` and `$ouput` variables in the `Command` class into the constructor of the Server class.

And to make it even more difficult, I also want the `$input` and `$output` variables accessible in the `MessageManager` class.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: `SymfonyStyle` actually only uses `Input`, but doesn't allow to access it. What exactly do you need `Input` for? You should use only variables it provides outside the `Command`.**

---

So, basically you need **`Input` and `Output` as a service**?

The class that combines them is called `SymfonyStyle` and it was introduced in in Symfony 2.8 with [nice blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-console-style-guide).

There are many ways to get input/output to `SymfonyStyle`, but I'll show you the most straighforward one. I use it in [Symplify](https://github.com/symplify/symplify) packages and [Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) for over 3 years and it is very reliable.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

final class SymfonyStyleFactory
{
    public function create(): SymfonyStyle
    {
        $input = new ArgvInput();
        $output = new ConsoleOutput();

        return new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
    }
}
```

Then register this factory as a sevice:

```
# app/config/services.yaml
services:
    App\Console\SymfonyStyleFactory: ~

    Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle:
        factory: ['@App\Console\SymfonyStyleFactory', 'create']
```

Then just require `SymfonyStyle` in any service you need it in and use it:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1); 

class MessageManager
{
    /**
     * @var SymfonyStyle
     */
    private $symfonyStyle;

    public function __construct(SymfonyStyle $symfonyStyle)
    {
        $this->symfonStyle = $symfonyStyle;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        // some code
        $this->symfonyStyle->writeln('It works!');
        // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like what I'm trying to achieve, I'll try this when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Works in Symfony 6.1 in Fixtures like a charm. Thanks! Of course you can just do `return new SymfonyStyle(new ArgvInput(), new ConsoleOutput());` ;)

Answer (score -1):

The data that is in the concrete instance of the InputInterface is only created when the command is run, the same for Output. These would therefore be parameters that are passed into a function, from the `execute()` method, or another method that is eventually called. Similarly, they are parameters that can be given to a `Server` class method (and likely from there, to a `MessageManager` method).

They hold data, but they are not a service.